# A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile: org/apache/maven/shared/utils/StringUtils

Tags: rest, maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

i am beginner.. i am trying for spring boot wit rest service in spring tool suite..i hava copied  the project from website...i couldn't clear the error..which i posted as image..thanks in advance
this is my pom.xml...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>javainterviewpoint</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <name>javainterviewpoint</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


</project>
```

[image]

Comment: Please show full log output...

Comment: .. and please post it as text and not as image

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts here:

(1) in case you are running a recent version of the Spring Tool Suite (3.9.x) from https://spring.io/tools, you don't need to copy projects from websites in order to get started. You can just go to the wizard called "Import Spring Getting Started Content" and select, for example, the "Rest Service" guide. It will import the projects ready-to-use into your workspace.

(2) I don't know exactly what goes wrong with your build, but it looks like you are running a Maven command line build from within STS. You don't need to do that. STS comes with a Maven integration into your IDE that does everything for you. No need to run Maven builds from the command line or the context-menu. Just open the boot dashboard, select your project, and press "run".

(3) If you really want to run a Maven build from your command line, you can do that for sure. The picture that you posted doesn'T really reveal what goes wrong, but from your title (it mentions something about a missing class) I vaguely guess that it might be related to a broken or corrupt local maven cache. So delete your local maven repository (usually located at ~/.m2/repository) and run your build again. That will download all the necessary dependences again.

Hope this helps!